# Trouble finding chunk loading noise algorithm

Tags: python, noise, terrain, procedural-generation

I am working on a basic 2d terrain generator and currently It generates a 1024x1024 'swatch' of terrain using [perlin-numpy](https://github.com/pvigier/perlin-numpy).
I am interested in having the option to generate another 'chunk' (like Minecraft) above my current terrain that is different, but fits smoothly above my current terrain.

TL;DR:
the noise function I'm using takes `generate_fractal_noise_2d((1024, 1024), octaves=6)`

 I want to be able to do  `generate_fractal_noise_2d((1024, 1024), location=(<x coord of chunk (pixels)>, <y coord of chunk (pixels)>), octaves=6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is very easy with noise, because noise is a point evaluation function. This library would work if it provided an "offset" parameter, but it doesn't seem to. Also, is there a reason you are using a "Perlin" noise library and not an (Open)Simplex? Perlin is an older function for noise, which produces visually significant grid bias. (Open)Simplex can be noticeably better about that. You can see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZgCk.jpg) that the Perlin on top has a lot of 45 and 90 degree parts. Terrain features won't be distributed along a more interesting variety of directions.

Here's what I would do:

- Use [Python OpenSimplex](https://pypi.org/project/opensimplex/) instead.
- Implement octave summation manually, since the lib doesn't have it.

```py
class OpenSimplexFractal(object):

    def __init__(self, seed=0, octaves=6):
        self._instances = []
        for i in range(octaves):
            self._instances[i] = OpenSimplex(seed + i)
    
    def fractalNoise2(x, y, persistence=0.5, lacunarity=2, frequency=1, amplitude=1):
        value = 0
        for i in range(len(self._instances)):
            value += self._instances[i].noise2d(x * frequency, y * frequency) * amplitude
            amplitude *= persistence
            frequency *= lacunarity
        return value
```

- Populate your array manually. Here it is with a simple loop, but if you're familiar enough with numpy you could write it with its syntax.

```py
    
    def arrayFractalNoise2(shape, offset, persistence=0.5, lacunarity=2, frequency=1, amplitude=1):
        noise = np.zeros(shape)
        for y in range(shape[0]):
            for x in range(shape[1]):
                noise[y+offset[1],x+offset[0]] = fractalNoise2(x, y, persistence, lacunarity, frequency, amplitude)
    return noise
```

When generating the chunk at the origin, you would do `arrayFractalNoise2((1024, 1024), (0, 0), ...)`. But when generating the next chunk in X, you would do `arrayFractalNoise2((1024, 1024), (1024, 0), ...)` and so-on.

I may have made errors in my code, but I hope it's helpful as it is.

(I hereby release these code snippets under [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/share-your-work/public-domain/cc0/)).

Comment: Thanks! Ill try converting from perlin to simplex, I personally think Perlin looks nice but I consider versatility snd speed more valuable than looks ;)

Comment: Applying fBm to the noise is no prob, especially with NumPy, I am fairly familiar with numpy

Comment: Interesting. What about Perlin looks nicer... are you comparing to variants of Simplex which appear dotty? This lib doesn't have that! It's much smoother.

Comment: There are also variants of Simplex which don't look good in 2D because they use a poor gradient table, but the gradient table in this one is a bit better.And if you do have a "dotty" simplex implementation, the dottiness tends to disappear as you sum octaves, while the grid alignment of Perlin tends to stick around.

Comment: If you do like the distribution of Perlin, you can avoid the visible grid alignment by using the 3D noise and rotating to domain to hide the grid. There is a specific 'optimal' formula for producing a good plane in X,Y or in X,Z. See here: https://github.com/Auburn/FastNoise/blob/d7e3ed86c1c638bffd36cce5014557f76ac577f5/CSharp/FastNoiseLite.cs#L862 You would still need to do point evaluation manually though.

Comment: The image shown on that project page on top, does look *slightly* better than some Perlin impls I've seen, but there is still visible grid bias, and I highly suspect that if you zoom out even just a little, it will show immensely.

Comment: Is there any way to use this with python? https://github.com/Auburn/FastNoise2

Comment: You might be able to wrap it like this library wraps C. https://github.com/caseman/noise

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I have little to no experience with C++ or C

Comment: I have moderate experience with C/C++ but I have only just started to study linking it to Python. I don't think I have any reasonable advice I could give in that area yet unfortunately, aside from studying how it works and maybe researching the topic.

Comment: I might post another qestion on that topic